# PostgreSQL phpPgAdmin ENUM field

Tags: postgresql, enums, phppgadmin

I'm using PostgreSQL and phpPgAdmin for database manipulation. Now I have problem to create ENUM field with phpPgAdmin. Is it possible to do it with that tool and how?

Comment: Could you share your sql?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not; you'll need to enter the SQL directly.